# LF recommendations for a tool to generate a release readiness report

Tags: continuous-integration

I'm looking for some recommendations for a build readiness report tool which can automate the creation of a report consisting of the following:

1. A builds open defects
2. User stories/Requirements in a build
3. A builds test results
4. Trace-ability of defects, test cases, and requirements (all to each other).
5. Other various non-source code related documents (i.e. are they in the repository?)

We use Github and Rational Team Concert as our SCM tools. I've been looking at something tools like Jenkins, but am looking to see what other tools are out there.

Answer (score 0):

Just about all of these can be handled by Rational Team Concert. This assumes you are using RTC's work items for tracking.

1. You can report defects against a build.This will show in the build result links on the overview tab (top right corner). The RTC dashboard can display all open defects for a given iteration. It can also report on build health. There are MANY out of the box dashboard widgets you can use. Some require that you have setup the underlying data warehouse and data collection component.
2. Work items with changes included in the build will be found on the Overview tab in the lower right corner (in the Contribution Summary). You can also use the Jazz Reporting Service to dynamically generate reports that include more detailed information including parent stories (and even parent Epics if they exist).
3. If you are doing an ANT or Maven based build, you can report back the results to the build result. Edit the build definition and check the options for Junit Publishing. This will create a JUnit tab on the build result and display all the unit test results. You may need to add the build toolkit to the ANT or Maven execution path. If you are using Jenkins for your build instead of the Jazz Build Engine, see this article: https://jazz.net/library/article/350
4. This requires that you also have a test tool such as Quality Manager, and a requirements tool such as DOORs NG. When setup correctly, you can get traceability matrices within all of the tools that give you a total map of what has been requested, what has been built, and what has been tested. See this video about traceability: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNRGalOwX18
5. I'd recommend you explore the Dashboard and widget catalog for available reports. As long as you are using work items and kicking off builds from within RTC (even if it uses Jenkins for the build engine), then you can get a TON of data.